# Transfer content from one DIV to another whenever window resizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, resize

I am trying to transfer some content from one DIV to another whenever browser window resizes to a specific size or less. This is my code:

```
$(function () {

    function transferContent() {
        if ($(this).height() < 500) $(".target").html($(".source").html());
    }

    $(window).on("resize", transferContent);

});
```

And this is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/76yjw0rs/

Please tell me how to do it?

Comment: you had a syntax error and you werent including jquery. See it working here https://jsfiddle.net/76yjw0rs/1/

Comment: let me know if you meant something else

Comment: Oh..Thanks. How could I forgot including JQuery. Well this solves one problem. But I want that if height is less then some specified height than source html should be transferred to target and back to source if height increases more than 500.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  var content = $('.source').html();

  function transferContent() {
    if ($(this).height() < 500) {
      $(".target").html(content);
        $(".source").empty();
    }
    else{
      $(".source").html(content);
        $(".target").empty();
      }
  }
  $(window).on("resize", transferContent);

});
```

```css
.target {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  color: white
}
.source {
  color: white;
  background-color: brown
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="target"></div>
<div class="source">CONTENT</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @AmmarCSE this worked like a charm. :) But one question is that why the color of `source` DIV changes to white when content is transferred to `target` DIV?

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva, sorry just got back. I dont think its the color that is changing to white. Rather, it is because the content is empty so the div no longer has a width/height. You should be able to overcome this by putting a static width/height in the css. Let me know if you need help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted to check if the window height is less than 500, but you use `$(this).height()`. Rewrite `$(this)` to `$(window)`.

Comment: The event is called on `window`. So, `this` will point to `window`.